# Select duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to get duplicate rows in sql

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, COUNT(*)
FROM
    emp
GROUP BY
    col1, col2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

I have used col1, col2 here to match duplicates but what if I have 1000 more columns will I write all of there names? Like :

```
SELECT
    col1, col2,...,col1000 COUNT(*)
FROM
    emp
GROUP BY
    col1, col2...,col1000
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Or is there any better way?

Comment: You can save the query as a view, so you need not write the complete query again.

Comment: You can do something like this: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS allcolumns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = "yourtable" ; This will produce a comma-separated list of all column names of your table. This can be used by your application or saved as a view like proposed.

Comment: Is your desired result a list of duplicate rows?

Comment: In general, yes, you will need to write all columns' names. Since the value of each of your columns can change the outcome of your query, you do have to explicitly specify them all.

Comment: I doubt you will ever have a table with 1000 columns. Here's a blog that goes into a deep description of how many columns can a MySQL table support: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/08/understanding-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-mysql-table/

Comment: @etsuhisa yes it is.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes It doesn't have 1000 columns it was just example to what to do if the number of column increases.